# Node.js and express middleware error on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku, express, deployment, yeoman

I'm deploying my Yeomoan :angular app to Heroku, but I can't seem to configure the server properly and am getting errors the Middleware like logger is not longer bundled in Express. So I have tried to include Morgan (logger) in the web server file.

I've set up the web.js file as follows:

```
 /**
 * Created by lindakeating on 30/07/15.
 */
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var app = express();


app.use(logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

And my Procfile calls the the web.js file like this:

```
web: node web.js
```

And in the package.json file I have the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "gzippo": "^0.2.0",
    "method-override": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.2.2"
  },
```

However when I deploy to heroku and check heroku logs I see the following error:

> Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express
>   and must be installed separately. Please see
>   https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

I believe this is because since Express 4.0 the middleware is no longer bundled.  So I downloaded and installed Morgan and have told the Web.js file to use morgan.

When I run `foreman start` the app runs as expected but once deployed on Heroku it does not.

I used Yeoman `yo angular` to generate the app. I'm not au fait enough with angular and the various different generators to know if that may be where my problem lies. Or where else to look.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this ? @LindaKeating